# Searching Flights

Tags: planning, flight-search-engines, itineraries

Planning a  trip overseas that goes from A to B; B to C; C home to A.
How do I search flights for this if I don't know best cities for multiple stops on each leg of trip.

Comment: Many flight search engines can do multi-city itineraries -- e.g. Google Flights.

Comment: Have you tried www.hipmunk.com, Google flights, kayak.com ? What specifically do you need that a these engine can't do ?